# How do I create a calculation in Cognito Forms that has two or more conditional outcomes?

Tags: cognito-forms

When building a form using [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), I am trying to create a discount code field that will accept 2 different codes and apply each with a different discount on the base rate.

I cannot figure out how to calculate the discount code when using more than one discount code.

E.g. : `CODE1 = 15% discount`; `CODE2 = 25% discount`. These discounts are applied to a selected `REGISTRATIONRATE`.

I found this code for the calculation of the discount amount on the Field Setting of Price:
`= CouponCode = "CODE1" ? -FullWeekendRegistration_Amount*.15  : 0`

which works for one couponcode only. 
What is the syntax to add the 2nd code? i.e. I want to say IF couponcode="CODE1" then apply a 15% discount to the base rate else if couponcode="CODE2" then apply a 25%.
discount to the base rate.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what Web app you're talking about. It's obviously not IFTTT.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The example you included was from [this blog post](http://blog.cognitoapps.com/3-easy-ways-to-create-discounts-on-payment-forms) on three ways to implement discounts in Cognito Forms.

The syntax for the discount calculation would be:

```
=CouponCode = "CODE1" ? 0.15 : CouponCode = "CODE2" ? 0.25 : 0
```

The syntax is a bit cryptic (used by JavaScript and other C languages), but generally it is:

```
[condition] ? [true result] : [false result]
```

But you can chain them together indefinitely like:

```
[condition 1] ? [true result 1] : [condition 2] ? [true result 2] : [condition 3] ? [true result 3] : [false result]
```

The full documentation for calculations can be found on the [Cognito Forms help site](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations).